# Replacing Characters in String C#

Tags: c#, string, replace

I need to replace a series of characters in a file name in C#. After doing many searches, I can't find a good example of replacing all characters between two specific ones. For example, the file name would be:

"TestExample_serialNumber_Version_1.0_.pdf"

All I want is the final product to be "serialNumber".

Is there a special character I can use to replace all characters up to and including the first underscore? Then I can run the the replace method again to replace everything after the and including the next underscore? I've heard of using regex but I've done something similar to this in Java and it seemed much easier to accomplish. I must not be understanding the string formats in C#.

I would imagine it would look something like:

```
name.Replace("T?_", "");//where ? equals any characters between
name.Replace("_?", "");
```

Comment: Why not split and then get the second item, `"TestExample_serialNumber_Version_1.0_.pdf".Split('_')[1]`

Comment: Use a regular expression. Should be fairly straightforward. You said you've "done something similar...in Java", so what would that look like? What difficulty are you having translating that to C#?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than "replace", just use a regex to extract the part you want. Something like:

```
(?:TestExample_)(.*)(?:_Version)
```

Would give you the `serialnumber` part in a capture group.

Or if `TestExample` is variable (in which case, you need your question to be *more* specific about exactly what patten you are matching) you could probably just do:

```
(?:_)(.*)(?:_Version)
```

Assuming the `Version` part *is* constant.

In `C#`, you could do something like:

```
var regex1 = new Regex("(?:TestExample_)(.*)(?:_Version)");
string testString = "TestExample_serialNumber_Version_1.0_.pdf";        
string serialNum = regex1.Match(testString).Groups[1].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to regex, you could find the first instance of an underscore then find the next instance of an underscore and take the substring between those indices.

```
string myStr = "TestExample_serialNumber_Version_1.0_.pdf";
string splitStr = "_";
int startIndex = myStr.IndexOf(splitStr) + 1;
string serialNum = myStr.Substring(startIndex, myStr.IndexOf(splitStr, startIndex) - startIndex);
```